# How can I share large numpy arrays between python processes, e.g. jupyter notebooks, without duplicating them in memory?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have large numpy arrays that I want to share with other python processes on the same machine without holding copies in memory. Specifically, my usecase is to share the array between jupyter notebooks on linux. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1: The array is already in memory in process 1 and you want to share it with process 2,3,4, ...

Given a numpy array arr, here is how it can be copied to shared memory:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory # requires python > 3.8

arr = np.array([1,2,3]) # array in memory that you want to share
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=arr.nbytes)
shm_arr = np.ndarray(arr.shape, dtype=arr.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
np.copyto(shm_arr, arr)
print(shm.name)
```

In the process 2,3,4, which can be other jupyter notebooks, you can then access the array as follows:

```
shape = 3, # adapt to shape of the array in process 1
dtype = 'int64' # adapt to dtype of the array in process 1
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='psm_554627ea') # adapt to name printed aove
shm_arr = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=shm.buf) # this now is the same array as in (sharing the memory with) process 1
```

Scenario 2: The array is on disk. This allows to directly load it into shared memory, avoiding the copyto operation above and is therefore more memory efficient.

Assume the array has been saved to disk in the past using the tofile method:

```
arr.tofile('/path/to/arr')
```

Now, in process 1 (e.g. the first jupyter notebook), we can directly load it into shared memory:

```
shape = 3, # adapt to shape of the array saved in the past. Note: shape and dtype are not stored in the file
dtype = 'int64' # adapt 
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=np.prod(shape) * np.dtype(dtype).itemsize)
shm_arr = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)  # create a numpy array from share memory  
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    f.readinto(shm.buf) # fill the array with the data from disk
print(shm.name) #
```

In process 2,3,4, you can then access the array as in scenario 1.